# MYSQL crosstab with daterange analysis: days as rows, sum as columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this, showing the dates where patients were administered:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `datefrom` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `timefrom` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

My data looks like this:

```
SELECT id, datefrom, dateto FROM table1;

1022, 2016-03-16 00:00:00, 2016-03-18 00:00:00
1023, 2016-03-18 00:00:00, 2016-03-24 00:00:00
1024, 2016-03-14 00:00:00, 0000-00-00 00:00:00
1025, 2016-03-29 00:00:00, 2016-03-31 00:00:00
1026, 2016-03-29 00:00:00, 2016-03-30 00:00:00
1027, 2016-03-30 00:00:00, 2016-03-31 00:00:00
1028, 2016-03-31 00:00:00, 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I'm interested in showing a crosstab with

- days as rows (starting at the min of `datefrom` and ending at the max of `dateto`)
- sum of patients, who were administered on this particular day

Additionally if no `dateto` is given, the patient is administered until today.

A expected result of the data above should look like (only first rows):

```
2016-03-14, 2
2016-03-15, 1
2016-03-16, 2
2016-03-17, 2
2016-03-18, 3
2016-03-19, 2
2016-03-20, 2
```

Comment: Add the expected result (with the already given input.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a collateral table with all dates (could be created once and filled with all day dates). Then you can use

```
SELECT adt.date_column,
       COUNT(*)
FROM the_all_dates_table adt
     JOIN table1 t1 ON adt.date_column BETWEEN t1.datefrom AND t1.dateto
GROUP BY adt.date_column
```